# How can i make 3 of this cards in a row CSS to transform this format

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

guys i already have a page it look like this:

[actually the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLhMs.png)

and i want it instead of 1 image per row, i want 3 of them per row (and reduce the space of them to fit 3 in a lane)

and this is my code actually:

<mat-step  [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" label="Selecciona Habitación">

```
  <div class="container"  *ngFor = 'let dummy of ListaPiezasView$ | async'>
    <!--desde aca puedes modificar lo que sea-->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="container-fliud">
        <div class="wrapper row">
          <div class="preview col-md-6">
            
            <div class="preview-pic tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="pic-1"><img src="{{dummy.foto}}" /></div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
      
          <div class="details col-md-6">
            <h3 class="product-title">{{dummy.codhabitacion__nombre}}</h3>
            <div class="rating">
              <div class="stars">
                <span><mat-icon class="estrella">star</mat-icon></span>
                <span ><mat-icon class="estrella">star</mat-icon></span>
                <span ><mat-icon class="estrella">star</mat-icon></span>
                <span ><mat-icon class="estrella">star</mat-icon></span>
                <span ><mat-icon class="estrella">star</mat-icon></span>
              </div>
              <h4 class="verde"><strong>Disponble</strong></h4>
            </div>
            <h4 class="price">{{dummy.accesorios}}</h4>
            <h4 class="price accesorioss">Precio: <span>{{dummy.precio}}</span></h4>
            <h4 class="price"><strong>Cantidad:</strong> {{dummy.cantidad}} </h4>
            <h4 class="price">Tamaño:<span  data-toggle="tooltip" title="small">{{dummy.tipocama}}</span></h4>
            <h4 class="price"><strong>Numero Habitación:</strong> {{dummy.numero}} </h4>
            <br>
            <input formControlName= dias>
            <div class="action">
              <mat-radio-group name="opList" formControlName="secondCtrl" required>
                <mat-radio-button  class="selecthabitacion price" (click)="recibirPieza(dummy);"   value="1" >Seleccionar Habitación</mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group> 
 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




<div>
  <button mat-button  matStepperPrevious>Atras</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="openSnackBar('¡Debes escoger una Habitación!', 'Entendido', 'red-snackbar')" matStepperNext>Siguiente</button>
  <div #btnRef></div>
</div>

<!--HASTA ACA PUEDES MODIFICAR-->
```

So what should i change in this code to make instead of 1 image per row, 3 images per row and reduce his size to fit 3 in a row

**UPDATE:**

[this is what i get with this code of @AmeRiza](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3UsK.png)

but im getting the img smaller and the cards are not using the full space, they are too narrow

the  original card is like this, but i want 3 in a row with a decent image size

[this is the card before the changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLhMs.png)

Comment: card is the parent element? By that I mean that is the highest level element that will be 3 in row?

Comment: I assume these ***cards*** are dynamically created?

Comment: Add `row` to your parent and then on each child add a `col-span` like `col-sm`

Comment: provide your css as well.

Answer (score 0):

you should create an element with "row" class and inside it repeat "col-4" class Every time  on "ngFor" directive's element.
change your code like this:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"  *ngFor = 'let dummy of ListaPiezasView$ | async'>
      <div class="card">
        <!-- your card element -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, ty for your help, i already implement your answer but im getting the img that i update in the main topic. The problem is the images are getting smaller, and the 3 are too narrow and are not using the space, can u help me to fix it?